# what does ep mask in the wordpress's register taxonomy function exactly do?

Tags: wordpress

I'm registering a custom taxonomy for my blog using the register_taxonomy function which has an argument `rewrite`

> for rewrite the URLs using some parameters

, one of them is `ep_mask` . **Wordpress** claims that it should be used when you want to add an endpoint for the Taxonomy URL. I just don't understand why to add an endpoint and what it's benefit. Please if an example with a result is available it will be better.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The endpoint mask value is used to tell WordPress what kind of endpoint additions a certain registered item supports, and to which a developer can add
endpoints to via `add_rewrite_endpoint()`.

By default taxonomies (as far as I know) offer no `ep_mask` (defaults to `EP_NONE`), but for custom taxonomies you could use a custom EP mask, or one of the built-in ones (e.g. `EP_PAGES`) to make the permalink structure work similarly to something else.

Assuming you set the `ep_mask` value to `EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES`, you could then register a new endpoint using

```
add_rewrite_endpoint('json', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES);
```

Which in turn would allow you to suffix your taxonomy URLs with `json` and the value `json` would be available as a query variable in `$wp_query`. Then you can use the value as a check to alter the query, templates, and other related things when the page loads.

You can read more about endpoints here: https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/ (A bit old, but should still reflect how the core works with endpoints.)

Comment: I understand the statement littraly but I cannot imagine what exactly happens when for example I used the EP_DATE ,with my registered taxonomy? . Please I need an example with a before and after results if you can

Comment: `EP_DATE`, `EP_PAGES` and so on are constants that refer integer values. Before applying the EP mask your tax URLs will work normally, but adding a query variable (e.g. `json`) will result in a 404 (as WP doesn't know what to do with said URL structure), but after adding the EP mask, you can map the endpoint and WP will not throw errors for extra stuff in the URL. If you use `EP_DATE`, all endpoints registered for that EP mask would be available in the taxonomy URL structures. I'll try to write a better example soon if I have the time.

Comment: But if I added the json I should now have both links availble like www.example.com/custom-taxonomy/ and  www.example.com/custom-taxonomy/json/ and both will work without problems

Comment: Yes, both would work like each other. But with the `json` version you could create some alterations in plugin or theme code where needed.

Comment: I really thank you for your help , SO now this what i have concluded . there is an ep_mask which adds the end point to the URL which then should be added to one of the predefined rewrite rules by the add_rewrite_rule function ,So if i defined the ep_mask with the value (e.g. Json) without adding the json endpoint to the predefined rules using the add_rewrite_rule function it won't work. Is this true?.

Comment: `add_rewrite_endpoint`, not `add_rewrite_rule`. Otherwise, that's the way it should work yes. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

The benefit is that you can use the endpoint with pretty permalinks.

> If you do not specify the EP_MASK, pretty permalinks will not work

The [description of `ep_mask` in the documentation of `register_taxonomy()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/register_taxonomy#Arguments) contains a [link to an article](https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/) that explains it in detail.

A quote from that article:

> If we wanted to add our endpoint to all post permalinks we would use `EP_PERMALINK`. For both posts and pages: `EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES`. For posts, pages, and categories: `EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES | EP_CATEGORIES`.

There are specific examples in that article:
https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/